# How to get these properties by SPFolder in C#

Tags: development

I have an SPFolder object here, but how can i find these properties of it?

> 1) site
>
> 2)subsite
>
> 3)library/List Name

For the first one, i can simply use `folder.ParentWeb.url`, but how about others?

code for create SPFolder:

```
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(id); //the GUID of the folder
```

Moreover, it is a server-side console app.

**Update**

```
Console.WriteLine(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);//subsite/libraryName/folder/sub folder


Console.WriteLine(folder.ParentListId); //00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SPList list = web.Lists[folder.ParentListId]; //error
var title = list.Title;

 Console.WriteLine("library: " + title);

var webs = folder.ParentWeb.Url;
Console.WriteLine(webs);//site name only, no subsite contained.
```

Answer (score 0):

`SPFolder.ParentWeb.Site` will give you the site collection object,
 `SPFolder.ParentWeb` will give you the subsite object.
 `SPFolder.ParentListId` will give you the list ID, which can be used to get the list title.

```
SPWeb web = folder.ParentWeb;
SPList list = web.Lists[folder.ParentListId];
var title = list.Ttile;
```

Comment: It brings error, please check my update

Comment: something is wrong with your `ParentListId`. It should be a valid GUID.

Comment: No, my library GUID is correct with this `SPList docLib = web.Lists["libraryName"];    Console.WriteLine("docLib: " + docLib.ID);` => fe153a49xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Ok, you get the web object using `folder.ParentWeb`. See my updated answer

Comment: But how can the SPWeb get the list for me which the `folder.ParentListId` still is 000000......... Moreover,  the error message is about List does not exist.

Comment: That is what I was saying `folder.ParentListId` should not show as 00000...

Comment: So why it is 000000. The SpFolder is created correctly that i can get its url, id.

Comment: not sure about that

Comment: I found why the  GUID is 0000. It is because i am the top level of the site.. if i use `SPWeb web = osite.OpenWeb("subsite")` i can then get the valid GUID. But the question is that the subsite is on the list which i want to find it. Therefore, how to get the subsite?

Comment: Read the answer , `SPFolder.ParentWeb` will give you the current sub site

Comment: No, it is the top level site, not sub site.. `Folder.ParentWeb.Url` => [http://topsite/](http://topsite/)

Comment: ParentWeb does indeed return the subweb, not the top level site.

Comment: folder.Item.ParentList can be used instead of web.Lists[folder.ParentListId]